# Rerender multiple h:panelGrid on change of h:selectOneMenu in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, selectonemenu

**The situation:**

I want to display specific panelGrid(s) on the page based on drop-down selection.  I am doing this by storing several boolean which get set to true/false based on which item is selected in the drop down. I use the onchange="submit()" to refresh/re-render the page.

**The problem:**

I have validation on many fields in the form, so if I select an item it does validation and will not display the form.

**The question:**

How do I get the selectOneMenu change to re-render only the set of controls on the page being impacted instead of the whole page and causing validation?

**The code: (JSF 1.2)**

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="list" value="#{sessionBean.myDecorator.selectedItem}" 
    onchange="submit()" immediate="true" required="true" 
    valueChangeListener="#{requestBean.listChanged}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--Select One--" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{sessionBean.myDecorator.mapItems}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Field causing validation:

```
<h:inputTextarea id="lblRequiredField" cols="100" rows="3" required="true" immediate="true" 
    value="#{sessionBean.myDecorator.myDo.myField}">
    <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="300" />  
</h:inputTextarea>
```

Comment: So, you have `immediate="true"` on all those other inputs too?

Comment: @BalusC I tried with and without immediate="true", neither seemed to make any difference - it continues to validate

Comment: It's hard to naildown the cause without a MCVE.

Comment: @BalusC Do you know if there is some other way to refresh only specific components rather than using onchange="submit()" ?

Comment: Use ajax, e.g. ajax4jsf.